# Disable link for menuItem in React Admin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

I have a react admin menu with a submenu, and I want the submenu to expand/collapse on click when you click the title OR the chevron. Right now, if you click the primary text, it triggers the navlink and navigates you to the dashboard (to=''). The dropdown works only if you click the chevron icon. I added a linkDisabled prop to the menuitem that acts as the wrapper for the submenu, but it doesn't work.

I tried another approach where I used mui listItems inside the multilevel menu, but the problem there is that when you click it closes the menu. If there were a way to stop the menu from closing onclick this approach would work best as it triggers the dropdown when you click the chevron or the title.

Here is the component that creates the submenu. The commented out code is what I originally did for the submenu:

```
const SubMenuItemMapper = (subGroup, groupName) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpen((prev) => !prev);
  };
  let subGroupTools = [];
  let curIcon = <PillarIcon />
  if (subGroup.length > 0) {
    subGroupTools = subGroup.map(MenuItemMapper(groupName));
    curIcon = createElement(subGroup[0].icon);
  }
  return (
    <MultiLevelMenu id="appSubMenu">
       <ListItem button onClick={handleClick}>
        <ListItemIcon>{curIcon}</ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary={subGroup[0].options.subGroup + ` (${subGroupTools.length})`} />
        {open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
      </ListItem>
      <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
        <List component="div" disablePadding>
          {subGroupTools}
        </List>
      </Collapse>
      {/* <MenuItem
        name={subGroup[0].options.subGroup}
        label={subGroup[0].options.subGroup + ` (${subGroupTools.length})`}
        icon={curIcon}
        to={''}
        linkDisabled
      > 
      {subGroupTools}
      </MenuItem> */}
    </MultiLevelMenu>
)};
```

And here is the component that renders the submenu:

```
const SuperCategory = ({resources, groupName, groupDisplayName, menuItemCategoryClassName, harmoneeTools, arbitraryTools, icon, ...props}) => {
  const classes = useMenuStyles();
  const menuObject = MenuObjectFunc(resources, groupName)
  const subGroup = menuObject.subGroup
  const groupArray = menuObject.groupArray
  let groupTools = []
  let subGroupTools = []
  let curIcon = <SettingsIcon />;
  // TODO: Eventually, we will want the harmonee folder to show up for everyone even if they cant access the admin tool
  // if (groupName !== 'harmonee' && group_array.length === 0) return null;
  if (groupArray.length === 0) return null;

  if (Object.keys(subGroup).length > 0) {
    subGroupTools = Object.keys(subGroup).map(subMenu => SubMenuItemMapper(subGroup[subMenu]));
  }
  if (groupArray.length > 0) {
    groupTools = groupArray.map(MenuItemMapper(groupName));
    curIcon = createElement(groupArray[0].icon);
  } else {
    curIcon = <SI2 />;
  }

  if(icon) {
    curIcon = icon;
  }

  // Grab the first? icon from the resources in the group
  // const curIcon = (groupArray && groupArray.length) > 0 ? createElement(groupArray[0].icon) : <SettingsIcon />;
  // TODO: Default to a different icon maybe?
  return (
    <MenuItemCategory
      key={props.key}
      className={menuItemCategoryClassName}
      name={groupName}
      label={groupDisplayName} // TODO: Harmonee to upperCase
      icon={curIcon}
    >
      <CardContent className={classes.menuCategoryCard}>
        <Typography variant='h5' gutterBottom>{groupDisplayName}</Typography>
        <Menu
        >
          {harmoneeTools ? 
            harmoneeTools.map(tool => (
              <MenuItem
                name={tool._id}
                to={`/dtx/harmonee/tools/${tool._id}/show`}
                label={tool.title}
                icon={<SI2 />} // TODO: Custom icons per tool?
              />
            ))
           : null}
          {groupTools}
          {subGroupTools}
          {arbitraryTools}
        </Menu>
      </CardContent>
    </MenuItemCategory>
  );
};
```

Relevant imports:

```
import {
  MenuItemLink,
  getResources,
  usePermissions,
  Responsive,
  useQueryWithStore,
} from 'react-admin';
import {
  Menu,
  MenuItem,
  MenuItemCategory,
  MultiLevelMenu,
} from '@react-admin/ra-navigation';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import Collapse from '@material-ui/core/Collapse';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
// Icons
import ExpandLess from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandLess';
import ExpandMore from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
```